# Checking for null in an instance function gets "Object possibly null" error

Tags: typescript

If I have an instance function, that checks if a property is not null, TypeScript gives an error 'Object possibly null' if I use the function in a conditional. However if I check for null directly, the error does not occur. How can I fix this?

```
type SomeType = {
     someFunc: Function;
}

class A {
    bar: SomeType | null;
    constructor() {
      this.bar = null;
    }
    hasBar() {
      return this.bar !== null;
    }

}

const a = new A();

if (a.hasBar()) {
    a.bar.someFunc(); // Throws object possibly null error
}

if (a.bar !== null) {
    a.bar.someFunc(); // Throws no error
}
```

Link to typescript playground: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20type%20SomeType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20someFunc%3A%20Function%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20SomeType%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.bar%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hasBar()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.bar%20!%3D%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(a.hasBar())%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a.bar.someFunc()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Throws%20object%20possibly%20null%20error%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) (Turn on strictNullChecks in options)

Comment: a.bar!.someFunc(). https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions

Comment: I don't want to change the conditional, I want to use the a.hasBar() function.

Comment: So what? Where did I suggest not to use a.hasBar()? Have you actually read my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know limitation of flow analysis. Checks inside functions will not have effects outside the function. See this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for more details.

The only type of function that can have an effect on flow analysis is a type guard:

```
function hasValue<T>(v: T| null): v is T {
    return v !== null;
}
const a = new A();

if (hasValue(a.bar)) {
    a.bar.someFunc(); // a.bar is not null
}
```